# Difference between update and pull command in fossil

Tags: commit, pull, fossil

Recently, i am working on fossil and get to know about its commit procedure. Also what is the difference between **update** and **pull** command? I am working in trunk branch and willing to get changes from remote repository and push local changes in just one command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. fossil add .
2. fossil commit -m "Initial Commit"

“pull” command will copy changes from the remote repository to the local repository. You could then use “update" to apply these changes to checked out files.